# ImageView и ProgressTab в ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, android-asynctask

Есть `ListView` в которое по нажатию кнопки должен добавлять новый элемент с `ProgressTab` и невидимое `ImageView`.

`ImageView` сразу начинает конвертироваться в нужное нам изображение через `AsyncTask` и прогресс конвертирования отображается в `ProgressTab`. Когда конвертирование закончилось, `ProgressTab` удаляется, а в`ImageView` сеттится картинка и она становится видимой.

---

Но после 3 или 4 повторения операции это перестает работать и в `ImageView` сразу сеттится рандомная из картинок, которые были обработаны до этого. (как я понял, такое происходит, когда элементы из `listView` перестают быть видными на экране).  Как это можно решить? И вообще правилен ли у меня подход?

**Код адаптера:**

```
public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

Context context;
List<Data> dataList;

public ListAdapter(Context context, List<Data> dataList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.dataList = dataList;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return dataList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return 0;
}

static class ViewHolder{
    ImageView image;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    View v = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inf = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = inf.inflate(R.layout.item_progress, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.image = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.itemProgress_previewImage);
        holder.progressBar = (ProgressBar) v.findViewById(R.id.itemProgress_progressBar);
        v.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    if (holder.progressBar.getProgress() == 0 && holder.progressBar.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
        ConvertImageTask convertImageTask = new ConvertImageTask(holder.progressBar, holder.image, dataList.get(position).getType());
        convertImageTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, dataList.get(position).getBitmap());
    }

    return v;
}
```

}

**Код Таска для конвертирования:**

```
public class ConvertImageTask extends AsyncTask<Bitmap, Integer, Bitmap> {

private static final String TAG = "WHALETAG";
Random random = new Random();
int timeout = random.nextInt(5)+2; // для искусственного замедления конвертации

private static final int TYPE_ROTATE = 0;
private static final int TYPE_INVERT = 1;
private static final int TYPE_MIRROR = 2;

private int type = -1;

ProgressBar bar;
ImageView image;
public ConvertImageTask(ProgressBar bar, ImageView imageView, int type) {
    this.bar = bar;
    this.image = imageView;
    this.type = type;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    bar.setMax(timeout);
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    int i = values[0];
    bar.setProgress(i);
}

@Override
protected Bitmap doInBackground(Bitmap... bitmaps) {

    Bitmap bitmap = bitmaps[0];

    switch(type){
        case TYPE_ROTATE:
            bitmap = rotateBitmap(bitmap);
            break;
        case TYPE_INVERT:
            bitmap = invertBitmap(bitmap);
            break;
        case TYPE_MIRROR:
            bitmap = mirrorBitmap(bitmap);
            break;
    }

    // Искусственно замедляем конвертацию
    for (int i=1; i<=timeout; i++) {
        Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground: осталось " + (timeout-i));
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000); // спим 1 секунду
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        publishProgress(i);
    }

    return bitmap;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
    super.onPostExecute(bitmap);
    Log.d(TAG, "onPostExecute: закончилась конвертация типа " + type);
    bar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

---

скажите, может правильнее будет поступить так:

1. Запускать асинкТаск, передавая в него (битмап для обработки, адаптер)

   - Внутри асинкТаска получать конвертированный bitmap и отправлять его в список битмапов.
   - По завершении таска вызывать `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`
2. В адаптере устанавливать готовый полученный `bitmap` в его `holder.imageView`?
   Вопрос только, как тогда обновлять progressBar по мере конвертирования?

Answer (score 3):

Обнулите картинку в `ImageView` перед началом загрузки:

```
if (holder.progressBar.getProgress() == 0 && holder.progressBar.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
{
    holder.image.setImageDrawable(null);
    //теперь запускайте скачивание
}
```

Comment: Не сработало. Картинки как гуляли по всему `ListView` так и гуляют.
Путем экспериментов выяснилось, что при добавлении нового элемента (т.е. когда должен начаться таск с обработкой изображения) таск не запускается вообще..

Comment: @whalemare, попробуйте не в doInBackground БитМапы передавать, а в конструктор. И вообще не понятное вы что-то делаете... И запускаете задачу как-то странно. должно быть что-то типа `convertImageTask.execute();`

Comment: @whalemare, а ещё ListView устарел и надо бы на RecyclerView переходить уже года 2 как.

Comment: @whalemare, да и картинки надо библиотеками грузить.

Comment: все равно.
Запускаю с ключом `AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR` чтобы была многопоточность, т.е. мог несколько прогрессБаров и картинок обрабатывать.
Переведу все на RecyclerView

Comment: посмотрите обновил вопрос текстом, который пишу ниже.

скажите, может правильнее будет поступить так:
1. Запускать асинкТаск, передавая в него (битмап для обработки, адаптер)
1.2. Внутри асинкТаска получать конвертированный bitmap и отправлять его в список битмапов.
1.3. По завершении таска вызывать `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

2. В адаптере устанавливать готовый полученный `bitmap` в его `holder.imageView`?
Вопрос только, как тогда обновлять progressBar по мере конвертирования?